# Number of permutations $\sigma\in S_5$ such that $\sigma^{12}={\rm id}$?

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

$X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$
$\sigma:X\to X$
$\sigma^{12} = I\;$ and $\;\sigma(x)\ne x$
How many functions satisfy the above condition?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What does $n(x)$ mean ?

Comment: Do you want $f(x)\ne x$ for *every* $x\in X,$ or more reasonably just $f\ne I$?

Comment: Note that the question is not only to find the elements of order 12.

Comment: Think of the 12th power of the different cycle types.